# Process with randomized name

Tags: process

We have a centos server with customers running vps containers on it. When we run `ps auxwww` we see a randomly named process running (consuming a lot of bandwidth). Every time we check it is named differently: hx9hdoh0d, y98y9ydhi, 87t8gt8878 it's name changes.

What is enabling the change of name? It is suspicious that someone would wan't to protect a process like this.

Comment: What do you mean by "what is enabling the change of name"? A process can name itself whatever it likes whenever it likes by changing the contents of `argv`. If it's the same process, you might consider inspecting it by PID instead.

Comment: Try for instance: `perl -e 'while(1) {$0 = ++$i}' & ps; ps`

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Please do note for anyone who just blindly copies that: This starts an **endless loop** on your system and you need to kill the process afterwards! At least it's no _forkbomb_ though… ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This sets off alarm bells for me.

Check its process ID, and look at `ls -l /proc/process_id/` to see e.g. what the executable is (the `exe` symlink). You could copy what that link points to for analysis. Also check what it's doing with `strace -p process_id`. If it's connecting to the internet, you may be able to firewall those outgoing connections while analyzing the situation.

If the `exe` location is somewhere in a temporary directory or somewhere else writeable by e.g. the web server process then it's a fairly sure bet that the system has been compromised. What user is it running as? If it's not root, then perhaps the damage done is limited and you *may* get away with cleaning up after it; however, I strongly recommend wiping the system, restoring from backup, and finding out how your system was compromised to prevent it happening again.